# Penalized regression: length of "positive" does not match

Tags: r, constraints, regression

I am trying to use penalized regression to predict data column y using the predictors month and time. I would like to include a positivity constraint on one of the predictors but not on the other. It is all working fine if I am using positive=TRUE or positive=FALSE but if I am using positive=c(T,T) or positive=c(T,F) I am getting the following error:

Error in .checkinput(match.call(), parent.frame()) : 
  length of "positive" does not match column count of "penalized"

although the length of the constraint and the length of the predictors matches.

The month predictor is a factor while time is numeric. However, changing month to a numeric variable doesn't help either. Here is my code:

```
library(penalized)
df<-data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-10-01"), by="days"))
df$month<-format(as.Date(df$date), "%m")
df$y<-runif(nrow(df),1,100)
df$time<- -floor(nrow(df)/2):(ceiling(nrow(df)/2)-1)/1000
df$month<-as.factor(df$month)

training<-df[1:200,]
test<-df[201,]

ens<-penalized(y, ~ month+time, ~ 0,lambda1=1, lambda2=1, positive =c(F,T), data=training)

pred<-predict(ens,~ month + time, ~0,data=test)
```

Can anyone spot what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`month` is categorical, so under the hood you end up with a design matrix with 11 columns (January through October + the time variable). This solves the problem:

```
ens<-penalized(y, ~ month+time, ~ 0,lambda1=1, lambda2=1, positive =c(rep(F,10),T), data=training)
```